# Is this test enough to determine if user is dragging?

Tags: winapi

I want to determine if user is dragging listview item, by pressing ( and holding ) left mouse button.

I am processing [`WM_MOUSEMOVE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645616%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and testing if user is dragging with `if( wParam & MK_LBUTTON )`.

Does this condition give me 100% accurate info about user dragging the mouse, or are there other pitfalls ( when testing like this ) I am unaware of?

Comment: A click will generate a wm_mousemove so the typical issue is to be able discriminate between a click and a drag-begin operation, DragDetect() can help with this.

Comment: @AlexK.: Listview sends [LVN_BEGINDRAG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774796%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to its parent window. I was thinking of subclassing listview to catch `WM_MOUSEMOVE` so I do not have to capture the mouse in the main window... Can you tell me when to use DragDetect -> in response to `LVN_BEGINDRAG` or in `WM_MOUSEMOVE` ?

Comment: LVN_BEGINDRAG is your guy

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: *LVN_BEGINDRAG is your guy* I apologize but I do not quite get it. I do not know how to use `DragDetect` in your suggested scenaio to determine if user finished dragging. Can you please help me? Thank you for offering advice, I find it useful as always.

Comment: You get that notification when the drag starts. Make a note that a drag operation has started.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: *Make a note that a drag operation has started.* If you mean something like creating `bool` flag, then I have already done that. I just wanted to use the `if` from the post to eliminate the necessity to introduce such variables. Otherwise, I do not follow you entirely...

Comment: What happens if the mouse is down but there is no drag active. Then your test is wrong. What's wrong with such variables anyway? Don't you need to make a note of which item is being dragged anyway?